# wso2 xpath selection on property value

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

in wso2 I've an xml as a local property containing a list of status with code and description (status_list).
I would like to select the correct status for one given code. This code is stored in a property.
I've tried something like

```
<property name="codes" expression="get-property('status_list')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:codes/status[@code='$ctx:code']" name="Test"/>
</log>
```

$ctx:codes/status is ok and display the list of all status but as soon as I want to "filter" them it's not working. 
Of courise if I hardcode a code the xpath is working.

```
<property expression="$ctx:codes/status[@code='code1']" name="Test"/>
```

Do you have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally I was not so far away from the response.
The following code is working

```
<property name="codes" expression="get-property('status_list')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:codes/status[@code=$ctx:code]" name="Test"/>
</log>
```

I simply had to remove the quotes...